# Highlight word and send GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I've created a text field in a Django model. I want to highlight words when word is clicked. I've found [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkYHG/1/)

How can I adjust it to send a GET request to Django when a word is selected to receive JSON from other website API? Thanks in advance!

```js
$(function() {
  editTxt('#myTxt');
  editTxt('#myTxtDiv');

  $('span').live('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hlight');
  });

  $('span').live('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hlight');
  });
});

function editTxt(selector) {
  $(function() {
    var newHtml = '';
    var words = $(selector).html().split(' ');

    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      newHtml += '<span>' + words[i] + '</span> ';
    }
    $(selector).html(newHtml);
  });
}
```

Comment: `How can I adjust it to send a GET request` Use [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax). Also note that jQuery 1.6.2 is almost 9 years out of date. You should update it to something on the 3.x branch. You will also need to remove `live()` and use [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do something like this by using [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
...
$("span").on("mouseover", function() {
  xhr = $(this).addClass("hlight");
  $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "YOUR_DJANGO_API_URL",
    data: { text: $(this).text() },
    success: function(data) {
      // replace HTML element or whatever.
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
$("span").on("mouseout", function() {
  xhr.abort();
  $(this).removeClass("hlight");
});
...
```

**Note** you have to replace data object `text` attribute to whatever your API backend parameters accepts, and as mentioned in the comments you don't need `.live()`

**Make sure to replace `YOUR_DJANGO_API_URL` with your backend API URL**